# Why NET 6 WebApplication wont configure Authorization middleware?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

While I was migrating the application to the NET 6 minimal API, I got an error saying that the authentication middleware was not configured.

Here's the JWT config:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IdentifiedUser", policy =>
                      policy.RequireClaim("User", "SR", "TR"));
});

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = appSettings.Jwt.ValidateIssuer,
                ValidateAudience = appSettings.Jwt.ValidateAudience,
                ValidateLifetime = appSettings.Jwt.ValidateLifetime,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = appSettings.Jwt.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
                ValidIssuer = appSettings.Jwt.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = appSettings.Jwt.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettings.Jwt.IssuerSigningKey))
            };
        });
```

The StartupManager class is one of the configuration classes held in the core lib that supports all of my microservices.

This is where the configuration method is called at the Program class.

```
WebApplication app = builder.Build();

_startupManager.Configure(app, _appSettings);
```

And the startupManager.Configure method, it is used by any microservices supported by the core lib.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, AppSettings appSettings)
{
    app.UseMetrics(appSettings);
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        [...]
    });

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseApiErrorHandlerMiddleware();
    
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    [...]
```

The error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Endpoint contains authorization
> metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization.

Configure your application startup by adding `app.UseAuthorization()` inside the call to `Configure(..)` in the application startup code. The call to app.UseAuthorization() must appear between app.UseRouting() and `app.UseEndpoints(...)`

Comment: It is not clear from your code what builder.Build() is doing and how this ties into the startup manager class. For example, your configure method expects a *builder* but you are passing the application itself. Should you call configure before calling builder.Build()?